# When fetchPolicy is 'network-only', data is inconsistency fetched

Tags: javascript, reactjs, graphql

I have a 'form' component that renders data that returns from BE using (graphQL).
See below:

```
  <StyledContainer>
    <formiForm type="warning" />
    <formiForm type="info" />
  </StyledContainer>
```

The 'formiForm' file, contains a GET request for getting the data:

```
const { queryData = {}, error, isFetching } = useQuery({
id: 'formData',
fetchPolicy: 'network-only',
query: GET_DATA,
variables: { id, type }
});
```

They are using the same request but with different 'type' value (doing 2 GET requests).

Expected behavior:
I want to be able and view 2 different forms with 2 different data.

Actual behavior:
Getting 2 forms with the same data, data changes from a refresh to refresh.

I am using:
`fetchPolicy: 'network-only'`
For being able that data will change when I am doing changes inside the form.
When I used with:
`fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'`
The data was rendered fine, but couldn't see changes inside the form after saving changes.

How I can handle this? How can I able to render all the data inside the form when using 'fetchPolicy' is 'network-only'?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I was needed to add an "Id" inside the graphQL query, to uniqify each render.